# Changing the layout of MPI communication: from MPI_ISEND/MPI_IRECV to others

Tags: fortran, mpi, distributed-computing, openmpi

I am solving a problem for unstructured meshes and the source and destination for communication are therefore saved in arrays. My question is how can I change this layout using `MPI_BSend` and/or using `MPI_SendRecv`?

```
    integer:: status(MPI_STATUS_SIZE, (5*(total_send+total_recv))), &
              req(5*(total_send+total_recv))

    do i = 1, total_recv
       j = (i-1) * 5 + 1   !Note that 5 comes from the 5 arrays: A, B, C, D, and E
       k = index_element_recv(i)   ;   source = index_node_recv(i)
       call MPI_IRECV (A(k), 1, MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION, source, tag1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, req(j), ierr)
       call MPI_IRECV (B(k), 1, MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION, source, tag2, MPI_COMM_WORLD, req(j+1), ierr)
       call MPI_IRECV (C(k), 1, MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION, source, tag3, MPI_COMM_WORLD, req(j+2), ierr)
       call MPI_IRECV (D(k), 1, MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION, source, tag4, MPI_COMM_WORLD, req(j+3), ierr)
       call MPI_IRECV (E(k), 1, MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION, source, tag5, MPI_COMM_WORLD, req(j+4), ierr)
    end do

    l = 5 * total_recv     !Note that 5 comes from the 5 arrays: A, B, C, D, and E
    do i = 1, total_send
       j = (i-1) * 5 + 1   !Note that 5 comes from the 5 arrays: A, B, C, D, and E
       k = index_element_send(i)   ;   dest = index_node_send(i)
       call MPI_ISEND (A(k), 1, MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION, dest, tag1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, req(j+l), ierr)
       call MPI_ISEND (B(k), 1, MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION, dest, tag2, MPI_COMM_WORLD, req(j+l+1), ierr)
       call MPI_ISEND (C(k), 1, MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION, dest, tag3, MPI_COMM_WORLD, req(j+l+2), ierr)
       call MPI_ISEND (D(k), 1, MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION, dest, tag4, MPI_COMM_WORLD, req(j+l+3), ierr)
       call MPI_ISEND (E(k), 1, MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION, dest, tag5, MPI_COMM_WORLD, req(j+l+4), ierr)
    end do

    call MPI_WAITALL ( (5*(total_send+total_recv)), req, status, ierr)
```

PS:

1. Why I want to know this is because I want to test the performance of some communication styles in my code.
2. `index_element_send` is NOT same with `index_element_recv`, thus NOT overwriting each other.
3. `total_send` and `total_recv` are NOT ALWAYS same.
4. Note that `tag1=1, tag2=2, ...`
5. If you have any idea how to optimize it better, please let me know. Thanks.

---

Extra: I have applied the layout below for `MPI_Bsend` but it gave an error when executed. Do you have any suggestion?

```
integer, parameter :: dp = selected_real_kind(15,307)
real(kind = dp):: buffer(5*total_send*8)

do i = 1, total_send
   j = index_element_send(i)   ;   dest = index_node_send(i)
   call MPI_BUFFER_ATTACH (buffer, 5*total_send*8+MPI_BSEND_OVERHEAD, ierr)
   call MPI_BSEND (A(j), 1, MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION, dest, tag1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, ierr)
   call MPI_BSEND (B(j), 1, MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION, dest, tag2, MPI_COMM_WORLD, ierr)
   call MPI_BSEND (C(j), 1, MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION, dest, tag3, MPI_COMM_WORLD, ierr)
   call MPI_BSEND (D(j), 1, MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION, dest, tag4, MPI_COMM_WORLD, ierr)
   call MPI_BSEND (E(j), 1, MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION, dest, tag5, MPI_COMM_WORLD, ierr)     
end do

do i = 1, total_recv
   j = index_element_recv(i)   ;   source = index_node_recv(i)
   call MPI_RECV (A(j), 1, MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION, source, tag1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, ierr)
   call MPI_RECV (B(j), 1, MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION, source, tag2, MPI_COMM_WORLD, ierr)
   call MPI_RECV (C(j), 1, MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION, source, tag3, MPI_COMM_WORLD, ierr)
   call MPI_RECV (D(j), 1, MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION, source, tag4, MPI_COMM_WORLD, ierr)
   call MPI_RECV (E(j), 1, MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION, source, tag5, MPI_COMM_WORLD, ierr)
   if ( i <= tot_comm_cells_edges_Ns ) &
        call MPI_BUFFER_DETACH (buffer, 5*total_send*8, ierr) 
end do
```

Comment: At first, you should really use some local buffers in order to have one `MPI_Isend()` and one `MPI_Irecv()` per iteration. `MPI_Bsend()` is evil and you should not use it unless you know exactly what you are doing.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet: Many thanks. I understood the concept of MPI_Bsend but I am confused with the layout. Could you please post the layout using MPI_Bsend()?